# How to include a latex document into a markdown using yaml metadata `include-after-body`

Tags: pandoc

I want include a latex document into a  markdown `.md` file using the `YAML metadata`. I have two files in a directory:

`markdown.md`

```
---
title: test fuer pdf eingeschlossen
author: AUF
keywords: test
abstract: Versuch
publish: True
include-after-body: testlatex.tex
---

A simple exampe for a test.
```

and `testlatex.tex`

```
some text without sense

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  firstly, a fundamental human need is;
\item
  secondly, a cost-effective technical mean,

\end{itemize}
```

I can include the `testlatex.tex` file into the body of the `markdown.md` on the commandline with

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex --toc -o test.pdf markdown.md  --include-after-body=testlatex.tex
```

but the equivalent value put into the `YAML metadata` seems not to have any effect (`author` and `title` are however used). I thought that the value included on the command line or in the `YAML metadata` would be equivalent. I checked in the pandoc latex template and see there an include for the `include-after` but I also wonder where the filename is converted to its content.

If I put 
`include-after: testlatex.tex` 
in the `YAML metadata` the name of the file is printed in the output, but the file content is not used!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is a corresponding YAML metadata field called `include-after`... [as documented](https://pandoc.org), but that doesn't take a file name. This issue might fix this in the future... https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4627

Comment: Thank you. I saw once a list for the correspondance between the pandoc options on the command line and the YAML arguments, but cannot find it anymore. It would be useful to know, what is or is not available using the YAML metadata.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of this? https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/doc/customizing-pandoc.md